# How can I load jQuery if it is not already loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

I have a **initializor.js** that contains the following:

```
if(typeof jQuery=='undefined')
{
    var headTag = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var jqTag = document.createElement('script');
    jqTag.type = 'text/javascript';
    jqTag.src = 'jquery.js';
    headTag.appendChild(jqTag);
}
```

I am then including that file somewhere on another page. The code checks if jQuery is loaded, and if it isn't, adds it to the Head tag.

However, jQuery is not initializing, because in my main document, I have a few events declared just to test this. I also tried writing some jQuery code below the check, and Firebug said:

> "jQuery is undefined".

Is there a way to do this? Firebug shows the jquery inclusion tag within the head tag!

Also, can I dynamically add code into the `$(document).ready()` event? Or wouldn't it be necessary just to add some Click events to a few elements?

Comment: Yes you can keep using $(document).ready jQuery will just fire it immediately if it is already loaded.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

jQuery is not available immediately as you are loading it asynchronously (by appending it to the `<head>`). You would have to add an onload listener to the script (`jqTag`) to detect when it loads and then run your code.

e.g.

```
function myJQueryCode() {
    //Do stuff with jQuery
}

if(typeof jQuery=='undefined') {
    var headTag = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var jqTag = document.createElement('script');
    jqTag.type = 'text/javascript';
    jqTag.src = 'jquery.js';
    jqTag.onload = myJQueryCode;
    headTag.appendChild(jqTag);
} else {
     myJQueryCode();
}
```

Comment: Will try that! add my button onclick handler in there, right?

Comment: Yup, and anything that needs jQuery. You would also need to run the code if jQuery is already defined.

Comment: would that equal to jQuery's onready event? Because we all hear preaches about writing event handlers in the **ready** event, right?

Comment: This did it, thanks!! Also, this is the most painless solution of all :)

Comment: @luqita Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845762/onload-handler-for-script-tag-in-internet-explorer

Answer (score 36):

To include jQuery you should use this:

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="jquery.js">\x3C/script>')</script>
```

it uses the [Google CDN](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery) but provides a fallback an has a protocol relative URL.

**Note**: Be sure to change the version number to the latest version

---

if `window.jQuery` is defined, it will not continue to read the line since it is an or that already contains a true value, if not it wil (document.)write the value
see: [theHTML5Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/)

also: you forgot the quotes, if jQuery is not defined:

```
typeof window.jQuery === "undefined" //true
typeof window.jQuery == undefined //false ,this is wrong
```

you could also:

```
window.jQuery === undefined //true
```

Comment: The js file I am including, will not be included at the top of the page, but rather within a div or something. Cant I use createElement method?

Comment: it should work, but you're not calling it see end of post, I would append it to the body. And you should always load JS on the end of the page (best practice for page speed/rendering)

Comment: @gar-onn - Why are you doing "==="? Firebug screams at me when I do it. I changed mine to if(typeof jQuery=="undefined")

Comment: Did I miss the memo? Why are you and Steve telling Jeff to use an old version of JQuery?

Comment: was an old snipet, cahnged it to the current version

Comment: I would prefer doing this without any 3rd party libs

Comment: it is the same lib, it only loads faster (witch is better), you can also use: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js or an other from this site: http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#CDN_Hosted_jQuery.

Comment: @gar-onn - I was referring to Stevens method :)

Comment: This one worked great for me! the "\x3C/Script>" portion when closing the script tag was the part that I needed.  I tried document.write to write out the script tag, but the "</script>" was detected as a script closing tag even when in quotes.

Answer (score 15):

If you're in an async function, you could use `await` like this:

```
if(!window.jQuery){
    let script = document.createElement('script');
    document.head.appendChild(script);
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js";
    await script.onload
}
/* Your jQuery code here */
```

If you're not, you can use `(async function(){/*all the code*/})()` to wrap and run all the code inside one

.

---

Alternatively, refactoring [Adam Heath's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6813409/3577695) (this is more readable IMO). Bottom line, you need to run the jQuery code AFTER jQuery finished loading.

```
jQueryCode = function(){
    // your jQuery code
}

if(window.jQuery)  jQueryCode();
else{   
    var script = document.createElement('script'); 
    document.head.appendChild(script);  
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js";

    script.onload = jQueryCode;
}
```

Or you could also wrap it in a function to change the order of the code

```
function runWithJQuery(jQueryCode){
    if(window.jQuery)  jQueryCode();
    else{   
        var script = document.createElement('script'); 
        document.head.appendChild(script);  
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js";
        script.onload = jQueryCode;
    }
}
runWithJQuery(function jQueryCode(){
    // your jQuery code
})
```

Answer (score 2):

The YepNope loader can be used to conditionally load scripts, has quite a nice, easy to read syntax, they have an example of just this on their website.

You can get it from [their website](http://yepnopejs.com/).

Example taken from their website:

```
 yepnope([{
   load: 'http:/­/ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js',
   complete: function () {
     if (!window.jQuery) {
       yepnope('local/jquery.min.js');
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: I would prefer doing this without any 3rd party libs :)

Answer (score 0):

This site code is solved my problem.

```
function loadjQuery(url, success){
     var script = document.createElement('script');
     script.src = url;
     var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
     done = false;
     head.appendChild(script);
     // Attach handlers for all browsers
script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (!done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == 'loaded' || this.readyState == 'complete')) {
         done = true;
         success();
         script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = null;
         head.removeChild(script);        
    }
};
}
 if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined'){

loadjQuery('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js', function() {
        // Write your jQuery Code
       });
 } else { 
  // jQuery was already loaded
 // Write your jQuery Code
 }
```

http://99webtools.com/blog/load-jquery-if-not-already-loaded/

Answer (score 0):

This is old post but I create one workable solution tested on various places.

[Here is the code.](https://github.com/CreativForm/Load-jQuery-if-it-is-not-already-loaded)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(url, position, callback){
        // default values
        url = url || 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js';
        position = position || 0;

        // Check is jQuery exists
        if (!window.jQuery) {
            // Initialize <head>
            var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
            // Create <script> element
            var script = document.createElement("script");
            // Append URL
            script.src = url;
            // Append type
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            // Append script to <head>
            head.appendChild(script);
            // Move script on proper position
            head.insertBefore(script,head.childNodes[position]);

            script.onload = function(){
                if(typeof callback == 'function') {
                    callback(jQuery);
                }
            };
        } else {
            if(typeof callback == 'function') {
                callback(jQuery);
            }
        }
    }('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js', 5, function($){ 
        console.log($);
    }));
</script>
```

Explanation you can find [HERE](https://github.com/CreativForm/Load-jQuery-if-it-is-not-already-loaded).