# Load jQuery with Javascript and use jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am appending the jQuery library to the dom using:

```
 var script = document.createElement('script');
 script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js';
 script.type = 'text/javascript';
 document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

However when I run:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){...
```

The console reports the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

How do I load jQuery dynamically as well as use it once it is in the dom?

Comment: Is there a reason you are wanting to do this vs the more optimized way?

Comment: Some answers in this question may help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474354/include-jquery-in-the-javascript-console

Comment: @Scott Yes. I have an application in which at installation it loads both jquery as well as a script. I need to load jquery within the script so that jquery does not break the users themes. I need to conditionally load javascript onto a certain webpage within their theme. Please just trust me on this.

Comment: Why would jQuery break the users' themes? If loading jQuery (which has no effect on css) can break themes, you're doing something very wrong.

Comment: Good point, but, What if they are using an older version of jQuery or another library?

Comment: @ThomasReggi - I think it would behoove you to explain how your application works with these "user themes" and possible duplicate versions of jQuery or other libraries.

Comment: Different versions of jQuery can actually live side-by-side in the same web page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528241/how-do-i-run-different-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically load a JavaScript file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294/dynamically-load-a-javascript-file)

Answer (score 154, accepted):

There's a working JSFiddle with a small example here, that demonstrates exactly what you are looking for *(unless I've misunderstood your request)*: http://jsfiddle.net/9N7Z2/188/

There are a few issues with that method of loading javascript dynamically. When it comes to the very basal frameworks, like jQuery, you actually probably want to load them statically, because otherwise, you would have to write a whole JavaScript loading framework...

You could use some of the existing JavaScript loaders, or write your own by watching for `window.jQuery` to get defined.

```js
// Immediately-invoked function expression
(function() {
  // Load the script
  const script = document.createElement("script");
  script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js';
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.addEventListener('load', () => {
    console.log(`jQuery ${$.fn.jquery} has been loaded successfully!`);
    // use jQuery below
  });
  document.head.appendChild(script);
})();
```

Just remember that if you need to support ***really*** old browsers, like IE8, `load` event handlers do not execute. In that case, you would need to poll for the existance of `window.jQuery` using repeated `window.setTimeout`. There is a working JSFiddle with that method here: http://jsfiddle.net/9N7Z2/3/

There are lots of people who have already done what you need to do. Check out some of the existing JavaScript Loader frameworks, like:

- <s>https://developers.google.com/loader/</s> (no longer documented)
- <s>http://yepnopejs.com/</s> (deprecated)
- http://requirejs.org/

Comment: This solution works, except for in WordPress.  Any way this can be modified to load jQuery into a different object ?

Comment: @SanuelJackson With Wordpress, you should use the `wp_enqueue_script()` function to include jQuery properly. Documentation: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script Some more information here: http://digwp.com/2009/06/including-jquery-in-wordpress-the-right-way/ or here: http://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/

Comment: Yes, what I was saying is that the above code does not work on Wordpress because it loads jQuery asyncronously as well. Even if this script is loaded at the very bottom of the page (just before closing html), jQuery isn't fully 'initialized' and thus it sees no jQuery loaded, and continues to load and do the callback.  Once loaded, it buggers up other things that were loaded async that depended on jQuery being loaded a different way (eg $, jQuery, etc), or dependant on a different version of jQuery.

Comment: It is great in the other cases I tried.  Was just making a note of the only glaring problem with this.  If somehow it could be tuned, but i don't think it is possible as it depends on detecting jQuery, which of course isn't loaded, and thus can only proceed with the logic of - if no jquery ... then ..

Comment: @atornblad can you help me to resolve the issue? At my it is working perfect in most of the cases as suggested by AWolf . But when require js or any other library used in 3rd party website then create conflict issue. so i want to use noconflict and change the $ and jQuery vaialbe in css. Check my link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28678039/load-jquery-dynamically-before-using-jquery/28678607

Comment: I've seen code that sets `script.async = true;`, and I hoped that setting it to `false` would make it so it doesn't continue with the current script until jQuery loads, like the simple but apparently dangerous  `document.write` does.

Comment: You don't need to do the polling, you can use only one line to wait until jquery loads using the .onload event like http://stackoverflow.com/a/42013269/3577695

Comment: The question *(and the original answer)* is from 2012, when people still unfortunately had to deal with IE8, which did not support the `load` event (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845762/onload-handler-for-script-tag-in-internet-explorer). Thank you for the downvote, pointing out that five years have passed. I have updated my answer.

Comment: In order to get jquery working, I had to change the "appendChild" to "prepend" !!!

Comment: Warning: the example script uses a really OUTDATED jQuery version from 5 years ago. The most recent version is 3.4.1

Comment: Yes,  both the question and the answer are from 2012.

Answer (score 8):

There is an other way to load jQuery dynamically ([source](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/load-jquery-only-if-not-present/)). You could also use

```
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"><\/script>');
```

It's considered bad practice to use `document.write`, but for sake of completion it's good to mention it.

See [Why is document.write considered a "bad practice"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice) for the reasons. The **pro** is that `document.write` does block your page from loading other assests, so there is no need to create a callback function.

Comment: I read the document you linked to, and for my use case of loading an older jQuery library for IE8, using document.write seems to be ok. It's working well for me so far.

Comment: This is the easiest most straightforward way to do this. Would there be a problem doing this at the beginning of a rather large script which is a separate JS file? It's too good to pass up.

Answer (score 6):

***[Encosia's website recommends:](http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/)***

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  // You may specify partial version numbers, such as "1" or "1.3",
  //  with the same result. Doing so will automatically load the 
  //  latest version matching that partial revision pattern 
  //  (e.g. 1.3 would load 1.3.2 today and 1 would load 1.7.2).
  google.load("jquery", "1.7.2");

  google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    // Place init code here instead of $(document).ready()
  });
</script>
```

But even he admits that it just doesn't compare to doing the following when it comes to optimal performance:

```
    <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.7.2.min.js">\x3C/script>')</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></scripts>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can only load one javascript. This would mean I'd have to load google jsapi dynamically then from with that load jquery? Seems redundant for my use case.

Comment: This is what a jQuery loader does.  You reference the loader and the loader injects jQuery into the document for you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to run your code AFTER jQuery finished loading

```
var script = document.createElement('script'); 
document.head.appendChild(script);    
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js";
script.onload = function(){
    // your jQuery code here
}
```

---

or if you're running it in an async function you could use `await` in the above code

```
var script = document.createElement('script'); 
document.head.appendChild(script);    
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js";
await script.onload
// your jQuery code here
```

If you want to check first if jQuery already exists in the page, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42013103/3577695)

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting this error is that JavaScript is not waiting for the script to be loaded, so when you run

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){...
```

there is not guarantee that the script is ready (and never will be).

This is not the most elegant solution but its workable.  Essentially you can check every 1 second for the jQuery object ad run a function when its loaded with your code in it.  I would add a timeout (say clearTimeout after its been run 20 times) as well to stop the check from occurring indefinitely.

```
var jQueryIsReady = function(){
    //Your JQuery code here
}

var checkJquery = function(){
    if(typeof jQuery === "undefined"){
        return false;
    }else{
        clearTimeout(interval);
        jQueryIsReady();
    }
}
var interval = setInterval(checkJquery,1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>

    <div id='status'>jQuery is not loaded yet.</div>
    <input type='button' value='Click here to load it.' onclick='load()' />

  </body>
</html>
```

Script:

```
   <script>

        load = function() {
          load.getScript("jquery-1.7.2.js");
          load.tryReady(0); // We will write this function later. It's responsible for waiting until jQuery loads before using it.
        }

        // dynamically load any javascript file.
        load.getScript = function(filename) {
          var script = document.createElement('script')
          script.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
          script.setAttribute("src", filename)
          if (typeof script!="undefined")
          document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script)
        }

        </script>
```

Comment: The difficult part is to run script *after* the script is loaded... And why would ever script be undefined!??

Answer (score 0):

Using [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) you can do the same thing in a safer way. You can just define your dependency on jquery and then execute the code you want using the dependency when it is loaded without polluting the namespace:

I generally recommend this library for managing all dependencies on Javascript. It's simple and allows for an efficient optimization of resource loading. However there's some [precautions](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html) you may need to take when using it with JQuery . My favourite way to deal with them is explained in this [github repo](https://github.com/jrburke/require-jquery) and reflected by the following code sample:

```
<title>jQuery+RequireJS Sample Page</title>
   <script src="scripts/require.js"></script>
   <script>
   require({
       baseUrl: 'scripts',
       paths: {
           jquery: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min'
       },
       priority: ['jquery']
    }, ['main']);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the *DevTools* console, you can run:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].innerHTML += '<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"><\/script>';
```

Check the available jQuery version at https://code.jquery.com/jquery/.

To check whether it's loaded, see: [Checking if jquery is loaded using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7341865/55075).

Answer (score 0):

ES6 Async version, allowing you to use it as a function anywhere you like (similar to [dynamic import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import)):

```js
/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10113434
 */
function loadScript(cfg) {
  const {
    url,
    global: globalName
  } = cfg;
  return new Promise((r, j) => {
    // Load the script
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.onload = function () {
      r(globalName && window[globalName]);
    };
    script.onerror = function (err) {
      j(err);
    };
    script.src = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
  });
}
```

Usage example:

```js
const jQuery = await loadScript({
  url: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js',
  global: 'jQuery'
});

jQuery('body')
```

NOTE: if you get `undefined`, you probably did not provide the correct `global` name.