# Load jQuery with JavaScript using Promises

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

[A previous question revealed how to load in jQuery using native JavaScript.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113366/load-jquery-with-javascript-and-use-jquery) I've successfully used the callback code from the answer there, replicated here:

```
// Anonymous "self-invoking" function
(function() {
    // Load the script
    var script = document.createElement("SCRIPT");
    script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js';
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);

    // Poll for jQuery to come into existance
    var checkReady = function(callback) {
        if (window.jQuery) {
            callback(jQuery);
        }
        else {
            window.setTimeout(function() { checkReady(callback); }, 100);
        }
    };

    // Start polling...
    checkReady(function($) {
        // Use $ here...
    });
})();
```

**How can I accomplish the same thing using [native JavaScript Promises?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)**

The reason I ask is because I suddenly need to chain off of the earlier callback, and it's a friggin' mess. I'm hoping Promises are a better way, and I have no real interest in using a loader framework.

Here's what I've got so far, but the Promise always ends up rejected:

```
// This code doesn't work quite right.
// Poll for jQuery to come into existance using a Promise
var jQueryReady = new Promise(
    function(resolve, reject) {

      // Load jQuery
      var script = document.createElement('SCRIPT');
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js';
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

      if (window.jQuery) {
        resolve("YAY");
      } else {
        reject("UGH");
      }
    });

jQueryReady.then(
  function(success) {
    console.log(success);
  },
  function(error) {
    console.error("Really helpful error:", error);
  });
```

(I'm sorry in advance for my complete ignorance.)

Comment: You would have to continue using your old code, and only resolve the promise when jquery is ready. There's no need to reject it in this case, unless jquery fails to load after a period of time.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a version that makes a simple `loadScript()` function that returns a promise and then provides a wrapper around it that detects whether jQuery is already loaded:

```
function loadScript(url) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.onload = resolve;
        script.onerror = reject;
        script.src = url;
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    });
}

function loadjQuery() {
    if (window.jQuery) {
        // already loaded and ready to go
        return Promise.resolve();
    } else {
        return loadScript('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js');
    }
}


// Usage:
loadjQuery().then(function() {
    // code here that uses jQuery
}, function() {
    // error loading jQuery
});
```

Notes on your code:

1. In your first code block, setting a single timer and assuming that the script will be loaded when that timer fires is like playing roulette.  It might work most of the time, but it is not a purely reliable method of doing things.  In addition, to be safe, you have to set the timer to a longer period of time than is usually necessary.  Instead, you should trigger based on the `onload` callback of the script.  Then you will know exactly when the script is ready with 100% reliability.
2. In your second code block, your promise version successfully handles the case where jQuery is already loaded, but then `rejects()` when jQuery must be custom loaded.  As you can see from my example, you need to `resolve()` when the newly loaded script tag has finished loading for your promise to work as desired.

Comment: Very useful, particularly with the abstracted `loadScript()` function in case I'd need to pull over other scripts in the future! And thanks for the notes on the existing code - I definitely had chasms in my knowledge in those areas.

Answer (score 1):

When you have multiple scripts with dependencies, I've found a promise sequence like this works best:

```
let p1 = loadScript('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js')
let p2 = loadScript('scripts/moment.min.js')
            
Promise.allSettled([p1, p2])
.then(function() {
    return loadScript('scripts/myScript.js')
}).then(function() {
    console.log('All Scripts Loaded!')
    initMyScript()
})
.catch(error => {
    console.error(error.message)
})


function loadScript(src) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    let script = document.createElement('script')
    script.src = src
    script.onload = resolve
    script.onerror = reject
    document.head.append(script)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Scripts inserted into the page in this way are executed asynchronously. (See ["Dynamically importing scripts"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement) on MDN.) As a result, `window.jQuery` will always be `undefined`.

Try attaching an `onload` handler to the script element such that resolution of the Promise is only performed once the script has been executed.

For example (before setting `script.src`):

```
script.onload = function () {
    if (window.jQuery) {
        resolve("YAY");
    } else {
        reject("UGH");
    }
};
```

As usual, this method is not compatible with all browsers. Check [this post out](http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/109) for ways to accommodate them.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that this is an asyncrhonous non-blocking way of loading javascript. You'll have to wait for the browser to download the script.

This is a possible solution:

```
var jQueryReady = new Promise(
  function(resolve, reject) {

    // Load jQuery
    var script = document.createElement('SCRIPT');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

    // You should also have a timeout in case your script never loads
    var timeoutHandler = setTimeout(10000, function() {
      if (checkIntervalHandler) clearInterval(checkIntervalHandler);
      reject("UGH");
    });

    var checkIntervalHandler = setInterval(500, function() {
      if (window.jQuery) {
        if(timeoutHandler) clearTimeout(timeoutHandler);
        resolve("YAY");
      }
    });
});
```