# How can i know when the library is fully loaded

Tags: javascript

how can i t change this code to run the function when the js library finish loading? uisng vanilla javascript

because i'm using a timer that didn't worked for slow internet connection

```
imported = document.createElement('script');
imported.src = 'https://pastebin.com/raw/dRap1YD8';
document.head.appendChild(imported);

    var delayInMilliseconds = 1000; 

setTimeout(function() {
.
.
.
}, delayInMilliseconds);
```

Note that pastebin is just for test

Comment: This has been asked before, you would want to look at Promises. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34638221/load-jquery-with-javascript-using-promises

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is the onLoad method. Take a look [here at the api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement), It's gonna look like

`imported.onload = function() { alert('loaded'); }`

Comment: Thank you, work like a charm

Answer (score 1):

Do like:

```
var imported = document.createElement('script');
imported.onload = function(){
  /* it's loaded - do stuff here */;
}
imported.src = 'https://pastebin.com/raw/dRap1YD8';
document.head.appendChild(imported);
```

Make sure you put your `load` Event before you assign the `.src`, otherwise it may never fire.

Comment: Thank you so much, i accepted the answer of @Mauricio because he replied first