# Calling javascript in javascript works for some but not all scripts

Tags: javascript

I have the following code in a script.js file that I call in my html file:

```
function loadScript(url)
{    
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = url;
    script.async = false;
    head.appendChild(script);
}

loadScript('https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6')
loadScript('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js')
loadScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.5.0/highlight.min.js')

hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
```

I use this code because I want to call only one .js file in my html instead of multiple .js files.

The first two scripts that I load to call [MathJax](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/basic/mathematics.html) work fine. The third script to call [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/usage/) however does not run.

When I paste all the code from the file 'highlight.min.js' into the my script.js file, the javascript does run normally when I open the html.

I don't understand why loading the 'highlight.min.js' file with the loadScript() does not work, or what I can do to get it to work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The script loading is asyncronous, so when `hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad()` is called the scripts are not loaded yet.

#### Alternative 1

You can modify your `loadScript()` function to make it work with promises, which resolve when the script is loaded ([taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34640578/974822)):

```
function loadScript(url) {    
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.onload = resolve;
        script.onerror = reject;
        script.src = url;
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    });
}
```

Now you can call your code and be sure that all libraries are loaded before calling `hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad()`:

```
(async function init() {
  await loadScript('https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6');
  await loadScript('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js')
  await loadScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.5.0/highlight.min.js')
  
  hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
})()
```

#### Alternative 2

You can modify your `loadScript()` function to make it load the scripts using `defer` and add an optional `onload` handler that you can use to call `hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad()`:

```
function loadScript(url, onload)
{    
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = url;
    script.async = false;
    script.onload = onload;
    head.appendChild(script);
}

loadScript('https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6')
loadScript('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js')
loadScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.5.0/highlight.min.js', () => {hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad()})
```

Comment: Umm why do I need a promise, can I just use the async attribute on my script element?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am clearly doing something wrong, because copying your code into my script.js file is not working, but when I add the following lines to my html <body>, highlight.js runs normally:: 

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.5.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>

Comment: @Jay you are right, you could use the `async = false` to defer loading, and then you could use the `onload` handler to call the function. I'll add this option to the answer.

Comment: Thank you but your answer will still never be as good as mine :) siek nah <3... nice answer! Lose the promise next time, promises are meant to be broken :)

Answer (score 1):

Wheres your onload handler?

```
script.onload = function(){};
```

Lets not worry about errors for now...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement

If the libs require each other then you need to defer because the child may be smaller than the parent.