# Including jQuery into JS File

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to load jQuery inside a js file and when I use include I get the error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: include is not defined

This is the code I have

```
include('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js');

(function (window) {
  "use strict";

  var config = {
    urlPrefix: "",
    visitsUrl: "/ahoy/visits",
    eventsUrl: "/ahoy/events",
    cookieDomain: null,
    page: null,
    platform: "Web",
    useBeacon: false,
    startOnReady: true
  };

  var ahoy = window.ahoy || window.Ahoy || {};

  ahoy.configure = function (options) {
    for (var key in options) {
      if (options.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        config[key] = options[key];
      }
    }
  };
.......
```

Is there a different way to load the jQuery?

Comment: `var jsCode = document.createElement('script');
  
  jsCode.setAttribute('src', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js');
  jsCode.onload = functiontoexecutewhenitisdoneloading;
  document.body.appendChild(jsCode);
       function functiontoexecutewhenitisdoneloading() {
          $('body').css({'background-color':'red'});
       }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load jQuery with Javascript and use jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113366/load-jquery-with-javascript-and-use-jquery)