# Jquery Script not loading in head when I create dynamically html page using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created dynamically new window in JavaScript and add some HTML code in it through JavaScript, but when I insert some script link into html head, it does not load when window is open.

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
function newWindowMap(){

    var myWindow = window.open('','_blank');
    var head = myWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var body = myWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

    var jqueryScript = myWindow.document.createElement('script');
    jqueryScript.src = 'jquery.min.js';
    jqueryScript.type = "text/javascript";
    head.appendChild(jqueryScript);

    var alertScr = myWindow.document.createElement('script');
    var inlineScript = 
 document.createTextNode('$(document).ready(function(){alert("Hello World!");});');
    alertScr.appendChild(inlineScript);
    body.appendChild(alertScr);

}
 </script>
```

Error on console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
>       at :1:1

Answer (score 2):

`$` is from JQuery, which is a popular library for JavaScript, and from the looks, you haven't imported it.

Add this into your head tag to fix the issue

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i already tried to do this but not solved the issue. the same problem persists.When i add jquery script in head of html, it works but when i do the same thing dynamically, it doesn't work. why is that?

Comment: Is the jquery script inserted *before* your own JavaScript code? If it isn't, then your code will not know what `$` is

Comment: I'm looking at your code, and is it that you are trying to load the JQuery script dynamically rather than when the html document is initialized?

Comment: its inserted in the header so, obviously before to my java script

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10113434/9070080) what you are looking for? (Assuming you are trying to load it dynamically)