# Include the jquery file dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to include the jquery file dynamically when I need to it.
But there is a problem, **the error message that appear** `$ is not defined`

**What I done:**

```
// include the file dynamically.
var parent, script;
parent = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "includes/jquery.js";
parent.appendChild(script);

// The usage
$('#box').remove();
```

Comment: try `script.onload = function () { $('#box').remove() }`

Comment: Does the error not occur if you include the script with a script tag?

Comment: @Archer: yes, not occur if you include the script with a script tag.

Comment: Possibily you can use this, [check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973647/dynamically-including-jquery-using-javascript-if-its-not-already-present)

Comment: I think @Pilot has hit the nail on the head then.

Comment: @LionKing do check ans posted below

Comment: @Pilot: Your answer works fine, but I wait maybe there is another way.

Comment: Possible duplication of SO Question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113366/load-jquery-with-javascript-and-use-jquery

Comment: @LionKing That is the best way to do it.  Using callbacks is, quite simply, correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For IE, I think you need to use the `onreadystatechange` callback. E.g.

```
script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (!script.readyState || script.readyState == 'loaded' ||
    script.readyState == 'complete') {
  $('#box').remove();
}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Handle `onload` event to make sure your script is loaded before you use it

```
script.onload = function () { $('#box').remove() }
parent.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: Your answer works fine on modern browsers, but this solution does not work fine on at least IE 7.

Comment: @LionKing did you really test it or blind test?..it will work in all browser..

Comment: No, not blind test, I have IE 6,7 and firefox and chrome. works fine on `ff` and `chrome` and `IE9`, but `IE 6, 7` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
(function () {

function loadScript(url, callback) {

    var script = document.createElement("script")
    script.type = "text/javascript";

    if (script.readyState) { //IE
        script.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (script.readyState == "loaded" || script.readyState == "complete") {
                script.onreadystatechange = null;
                callback();
            }
        };
    } else { //Others
        script.onload = function () {
            callback();
        };
    }

    script.src = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}

loadScript("includes/jquery.js", function () {

     //jQuery loaded
     console.log('jquery loaded');
     $('#box').remove();

});


})();
```